# Intercepting Exchange in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

Assume I have the route as follows

```
from("direct:A")
  .process(new ProcessA())
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "get")
  .recipientList( simple(httpUri + header("doc_id")), "false")
  .process(new ProcessB())
  .to("direct:B");
```

In the above path httpUri = "http4://localhost:25600". Now I am trying to intercept the message as follows.

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
         interceptSendToEndpoint("http4*")
         .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
         .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
               //TODO                                 
            }
         });
    }
});
```

The problem here is that the exchange is not being intercepted and context is actually trying to make a connection with httpUri host even there is skipSendToOriginalEndpoint.

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume this is in the context of a unit test extending `CamelTestSupport`, right?

Comment: yes Ray, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a dynamic route, which means that the endpoint is not known at definition-time. As a result you aren't going to be able to intercept based on the http endpoint.

What I would do instead is swap out the whole recipientList, rather than just the http destination called by the recipientList.

As simple way to do this using [weaveByType](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html). To weave in your processor, this would look like:

```
weaveByType(RecipientListDefinition.class).replace().process(...)
```

As always with adviceWith, make sure to implement `isUseAdviceWith` to return `true`, and to then call `context.start()` after advicing the routeDefinition.